# What does it mean for $X$ to carry the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

I am currently taking topology 1. A question I am working on states "Let $X$ be a set carrying the cofinite topology."

I am having trouble understanding what it means exactly for a set to carry a topology and cannot find anywhere it explains it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just means that the topology on $X$ is the cofinite topology: the open sets are $\varnothing$ and all sets of the form $X\setminus F$ such that $F$ is finite.

Comment: So, an equivalent statement would be: Let $(X,\tau)$ be the cofinite topology.

Comment: Not quite: it would ‘let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology on $X$’. $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is the topological space, not the topology itself.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When they say ``Let $X$ be a set carrying the cofinite topology," they want you to consider the topological space $(X,\tau)$ with underlying point-set $X$ and the topology given by the cofinite topology (which is the topology where the open sets are those subsets $U$ of $X$ such that $X\setminus U$ is finite or $U = \emptyset$).

Comment: Thank you! Much simpler answer than I thought!